# Can I add properties to an object in the Chrome debugger?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I know I can edit values or properties on an object in the Chrome debugger, but is there a way to add properties?

Edit: Here's an example of what I mean. In this popup window I can edit that values of these properties on this object. Is there a way I can add new properties to this object?

[image]

Comment: You mean like: `var obj = {};` [Enter] `obj.prop = 1;`?

Comment: Kind of. I mean when I'm debugging a javascript file and Chrome hits a break point. When you hover over an object a small window appears and you can change the values of the properties of that object in that window. Is there a way to add another property to that object?

Comment: `$scope.thing = "that";` [Enter]

Comment: Wow, that worked! I'm surprised I didn't know that. I suppose that is the answer to my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the example in your image, if you were stopped in debugging mode all you would have to do is enter something like `$scope.newProp = 'value';` into the console. The object will now have a new property while you continue to debug your program.

Comment: Was about to say the same. :) That's as simple as that.

Comment: That was it. Thanks! So simple